# session variable is not recognized anymore after migrating js code to assets/javascripts in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, session

I moved some javascript that was in a content_for(:after_js) at the end of an html page to a proper js file inside my assets/javascripts folder in my rails app.
I created a js.erb file that looks like this :

```
 <% if session[:user_role] == "asso" %>
    <%= render "javascripts/select_bar/_select_bar_asso.js"%>
 <% else %>
    <%= render "javascripts/select_bar/_select_bar_host.js"%>
  <% end %>
```

but now I always get the error :

undefined local variable or method `session' for #<#:0x007feb90e24400>.

It was working fine when the js was in the content_for(:after_js) at the end of my html.erb file and it was ok with the session variable.

What did I do wrong with my javascript migration ?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the *session* variable as local variable to the partial, take a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) and search for section **3.4.4 Passing Local Variables**.

To simplify, this is how you should render your js partial:

```
<%= render partial: "my_js", locals: {session: session} %>
```

Your partial should remain the same.